# Self Executing Script on timed schedule

Tags: php, mysql

I'm Working on a php app where I need to have a number count in a sql data base reset at the first of the month and at 12am everyday via PHP and MYSQL.

I have googled but found nothing. As far as I know PHP needs to be accessed by a client to be manipulated.

What is the best method of having the server do this on its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [crontab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

```
* 0 * * * /path/to/my/script
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use cronjobs. On windows 'scheduled tasks', on linux crontab. For linux:

`crontab -e`

A line have to look like this to be called every day 0 am:

`* 0 * * * /bin/php -q /script/path`

Or, to call the file via web but do not get the content:

`* 0 * * * wget --spider "http://url.com/cron.php"`

If you do not have a dedicated server, check your webspace control panel for this or ask your webhoster.

Comment: awesome thanks!, Alfwed answered first had to give it to him.